# Can I ask question regarding about battery holder for phone and camera battery?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question regarding about designing a flexible battery holder for a circuit board.

This flexible battery holder can take in most phone and/or camera battery. The circuit board have a LCD that display the battery voltage and have some variable resistor that control the output.

The output is a USB port and can be used to charge any electronic devices.

May I ask if I can post such a question on designing the flexible battery holder in electronics.stackexchange.com? If the question does not belong to here, please enlighten me which stackexchange.com site should I post this question to.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your question about the electrical design of the circuit or the mechanical design of the actual holder? Regarding the electrical design, what you've said here makes it sound like you have very little experience with such circuits ("some variable resistor" would not be a good choice here) and this particular project may very well be beyond you at this point in time.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for enlighten me. My question consists of two parts - one part on the mechanical design of the actual holder while the second part on the circuit design. I notice that there is no mechanical.stackexchange.com and was wondering where should I post the part one of the question to. Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: @user275517  To me, the proposed question sounds like "*design this thing for me: mechanics and circuit*".  A bit broad.

Comment: FYI, a practical need for a "variable resistor" automatically adjusted to achieve a given output is often accomplished via a linear voltage regulator.  But these are wasteful of energy; battery powered solutions typically use more efficient switching regulators (actually, most use a lipo cell with a lower output voltage than the desired 5v USB, so they use switching up-converters).  Anyway, it sounds like you are worried more about the mechanical capture of various surplus cells - you might look at "universal" battery charger designs for ideas (spring-loaded sliding contacts, etc).

Answer (score 1):

There is an engineering SE that is in [area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering).   A few more users and it will move to beta.

(sign up today!)

Comment: There was also a more specific proposal on Area51 for [Mechanical Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60942/mechanical-engineering), but it was in definition too long and got closed.